# How create entity class and mapping file for Materialized view in hibernate

Tags: hibernate-mapping

I need to create a entity class for oracle materialized view without primary key and also mappling xml file. i don't know how to do, can anybody give your suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate/JPA needs a primary key:

- [Hibernate without Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591255/hibernate-without-primary-key?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Hibernate mapping for a table with no primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500222/hibernate-mapping-for-a-table-with-no-primary-key?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [How to map hibernate mapping file without attribute id in the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106100/how-to-map-hibernate-mapping-file-without-attribute-id-in-the-class?answertab=votes#tab-top)

A possible solution is to create a new primary key everytime the materialized view will be refreshed and while creating it. You can do this by adding it to the create statement of the MV:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW viewname 
...
WITH PRIMARY KEY AS
SELECT 
rawtohex(sys_guid()) as ID, 
...
FROM tablename;
```